# How do I implement "inventory[0]" into If-Else Statements

Tags: c++, if-statement

So I'm currently trying to make a text-based game for my C++ class and can't seem to figure out how to make the if-else statement execute ONLY if there is a previously collected item in order for the story to make sense. If the item isn't in the inventory, the options for the players will be looped again for them to choose a different choice. I tried doing: `else if(input6 == "rub" || inventory[0] == "Purple Fruit")` but it would just execute the statement regardless of whether or not the player has the item. Thanks for your time!! I really mean it.

```
do {
    cout <<"You gotta start doing something quick before the swelling gets worse" <<endl;
    cout <<"Options are: \"rub\" the random substances oozing from your purple fruit onto your swelling neck, \"keep\" following the tracks until you could get help from the humans if those tracks actually belong to a human, or \"look\" around for anything to help cure your swelling neck\""<<endl;
    cin >>input6;

    if (input6 == "keep")
    {
        cout << "" <<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    else if (input6 == "look")
    {
        cout <<"Good luck" <<endl;
    }

    else if (input6 == "rub" || inventory[0] == "Purple Fruit")
    {
        cout << ".." <<endl;
        return 0;
    }

} while (input6 != "grab");

cout <<"Out"<<endl;
inventory[1] = "Pink Sap";
cout<< inventory[1] <<endl;
```

Comment: how do you compare strings?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare the strings by using "=".You need to use strcmp function to compare the strings .

Comment: The question is tagged C++, you can't know if OP uses `char` arrays or `std::string`s.

Comment: I can actually. I have no problem executing my programs when comparing strings using ==

Comment: I am not sure how you are comparing the strings in your code .As Quentin suggested it better you include your source here so that everyone can check it

Answer (score 0):

`else if (input6 == "rub" || inventory[0] == "Purple Fruit")` should instead be `else if (input6 == "rub" && inventory[0] == "Purple Fruit")` if you require "Purple Fruit" to be in the user's first inventory slot in order to use the "rub" command. You should add another case that handles the "rub" command if the user doesn't have "Purple Fruit" in their inventory as well. Consider something like this:

```
else if (input6 == "rub")
{
    if(inventory[0] == "Purple Fruit")
    {
        // user has item
    }
    else
    {
        // user does not have item
    }
}
```

Also, look in to using some kind of "set" class, like [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/), which will allow you to have an unordered collection of inventory items that you can query by name, instead of having to worry about which inventory position the item occupies.

For example, using [`std::set::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/) you can test if an item is in your inventory like this:

```
// assume inventory is std::set<std::string> and is already initalized and populated
if(inventory.find("Purple Fruit") != inventory.end())
{
    // item is in the inventory
}
else 
{
    // item is not in the inventory
}
```

Comment: What does the != inventory.end()) stand for ?

Comment: It's a little complicated to explain, but within standard library code there's a thing called an iterator. If you're familiar with `for` loops, like `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` an iterator is kind of like the variable `i`. An `std::set` doesn't have an order like an array does - in other words, there's no real notion of "the 2nd item" in a `set`. In order to "walk" through each item in a set, you use an iterator, like `for(std::set<std::string>::iterator it = inventory.begin(); it != inventory.end(); ++it)`, and inside your loop you can use `(*it)` to access the `std::string`. (part 2 below)

Comment: When you're using `std::set`, it's very fast and convenient to determine if there's a given value in the set or not. That's what [`std::set::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/) does. What `find` returns is an iterator, and the way you know it failed to find the thing you were looking for if it returns `<var name>.end()`, where `<var name>` is the variable holding your set. That is a special iterator value meaning "no more items" when you use it in a loop, as above, and it also works as a way of saying "I didn't find the thing you asked for." Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
if (input6 == "keep")
```

Assuming `input6` is defined as an array of `char` and is large enough to hold the given input, what you are doing is comparing the address of the array `input6` (since an array decays to a pointer to the first element in most contexts) and the address of the string constant `"keep"`.  This will always evaluate to false.

To compare the content of strings, use the `strcmp` function:

```
if (strcmp(input6, "keep") == 0)
```

This function returns 0 if both operands contain the same null terminated string.